# Quickest way to find the complement of two collections in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, complement, set-operations

I have two collections of type `ICollection<MyType>` called `c1` and `c2`. I'd like to find the set of items that are in `c2` that are not in `c1`, where the heuristic for equality is the `Id` property on `MyType`.

What is the quickest way to perform this in C# (3.0)?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx) and specifically the [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx) that accepts an `IEqualityComparer<MyType>`:

```
var complement = c2.Except(c1, new MyTypeEqualityComparer());
```

Note that this produces the set difference and thus duplicates in `c2` will only appear in the resulting `IEnumerable<MyType>` once. Here you need to implement `IEqualityComparer<MyType>` as something like

```
class MyTypeEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyType> {
    public bool Equals(MyType x, MyType y) {
        return x.Id.Equals(y.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyType obj) {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If using C# 3.0 + Linq:

```
var complement = from i2 in c2
                 where c1.FirstOrDefault(i1 => i2.Id == i1.Id) == null
                 select i2;
```

Loop through complement to get the items.

Comment: This will use nested loops and is very inefficient.

Comment: Maybe it's more efficient to use `where !c1.Any(i1 => i2.Id == i1.Id)` ? In this case you don't retrieve any value in the where condition, you just check for existence of the items. See  [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iQwS1v)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyTypeComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyType>
{
    public MyTypeComparer()
    {    
    }

    #region IComparer<MyType> Members

    public bool Equals(MyType x, MyType y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x.Id, y.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(MyType obj)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    #endregion     
}
```

Then, using Linq:

```
c3 collection = new collection().add(c1);
c3.add(c2);
var items = c3.Distinct(new MyTypeComparer());
```

You could also do it using generics and predicates. If you need a sample, let me know.

Comment: won't Distinct just filter out the duplicates leaving you with c1 union c2, instead of c1- c2?