# SQL Query -- Generate a 2 collections based on differences?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have 2 different lists:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
}

ICollection<Foo> OriginalCollection
ICollection<Foo> NewCollection
```

I want to generate 2 lists to be able to foreach them...

- All items that OriginalCollection contains that NewCollection does not (basically, a collection of stuff that was removed).
- All items that OriginalCollection does not contain that NewCollection does (basically, a collection of stuff that was added).

I know I'll get back an IEnumerable with LINQ, that's fine since I need to foreach. I just have no idea what my queries should look like...

---

Update:

I forgot to mention that I **did** try the Except clause... it failed because the objects are not the same. They only contain the same Id.

Comment: [101 LINQ Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want the Complement of the Set.
This post seems to fit your needs:

[Quickest way to find the complement of two collections in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193778/quickest-way-to-find-the-complement-of-two-collections-in-c)

Or perhaps the Enumerable.Except method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx

Comment: I updated my question b/c I forgot to mention that I did try the `Except` but it failed because the objects are not the same, they only contains the same Id.

Comment: Did you check out my first link? It describes how to specify your own custom EualityComparer so that Except will work the way you need.

Comment: so... link #1 is duplicate of my question. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

originalC.Except(newC, comparer);
newC.Except(originalC, comparer);
```

Following edit:

You can use the overload that takes a "IEqualityComparer comparer".

You can define a small class that implements that interface with any kind of compare logic you wish.

Comment: I updated my question b/c I forgot to mention that I did try the `Except` but it failed because the objects are not the same, they only contains the same Id.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the Except operator

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336761.aspx#except1

NewCollection -except> OriginalCollection = deleted

OriginalCollection -except> NewCollection = added

Comment: I updated my question b/c I forgot to mention that I did try the `Except` but it failed because the objects are not the same, they only contains the same Id.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Foo> original = ...
List<Foo> modified = ...
...
var deleted = original.Except(modified);
var added = modified.Except(original);
```

You could explicitly use `LINQ` but its not really worth it. One way could be:

```
var deleted = from i in original
              where !modified.Contains(i)
              select i;

var added = from i in modified
            where !original.Contains(i)
            select i;
```

Comment: I updated my question b/c I forgot to mention that I did try the `Except` but it failed because the objects are not the same, they only contains the same Id.